# from kafka import KafkaClient ImportError: No module named kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I installed Python version 3.8.3 and 2.7.16, `pip install pykafka`, and `pip install kafka-python`.
When I try to run the Python program with installed modules I get an error:

```
from kafka import KafkaClient ImportError: No module named kafka
from pykafka import KafkaClient ImportError: No module named pykafka
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want this for python 3.8.3. Use either `pip3 install kafka-python` or `python3 -m pip install kafka-python`. If you aren't using one of those python versions you can ditch it and then your original command will work. The problem is that you have 2 pythons, but you aren't experienced enough to divine which is being used at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting up a virtual env using [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) for instance. Probably the package has been installed for the python version you are not using.